# R purrr data manipulation with embedded xts objects using map / ifelse / when

Tags: r, xts, purrr

Below  a tibble with embedded xts objects

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)

Tickers <- c("AAPL","JNJ","KO","NKE")
Stock_Data <- sapply(Tickers, function(x) getSymbols(x,
from="1970-01-01",auto.assign = FALSE),
                 USE.NAMES = TRUE, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
 enframe(name="Ticker",value="Price_Data") %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(Price_2016 = map(Price_Data,function(x) x['2016'])) %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(n_days = map_dbl(Price_Data, function(x) ndays(x)))
```

Looking like this:
[image]

Now I would like to create a new column with only those xts objects where there are more than 10000 days.

```
Stock_Data <- Stock_Data %>% 
dplyr::mutate(Price_If = map(Price_Data,  ~ifelse(ndays(.x) > 10000,
                                                          .x,
                                                          NA)))
```

I have tried the above but get a list containing only one number where it should be the whole xts object when the condition is TRUE, see below:
[image]

then subsequently tried using when & map2

```
Stock_Data <- Stock_Data %>% 
dplyr::mutate(Price_If = map2(Price_Data,Price_2016,  ~when(ndays(.x) > 10000 ~ .x, 
                                            ndays(.x) <= 10000 ~ .y)))
```

And got this result:

[image]

How do I get to the right solution and what is actually going on with ifelse & when for the case where .x should be returned?

Comment: When I try to drill down by going `pd = Stock_Data$Price_Data[[2]]`, I find the function `ifelse(ndays(pd) > 10000, pd, NA)` has strange behaviour:  it returns 180 instead of just giving me back the xts `pd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question consists of two parts; let's look at them seperately:

1) `ifelse`

`ifelse` only works with "simple" values like vectors. You cannot use it to return more complex objects. See also the documented examples which already demonstrate unexpected behaviour for dates. However you could just use "normal" `if-else` blocks like this:

`Stock_Data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Price_If = map(Price_Data,  ~if(ndays(.x) > 10000) .x else NA))`

This leads to a similar result as your apprach with `map2`.

2) extract only a set of observations

I'm afraid you cannot extract a set of observations (rows) with `mutate`. `mutate` adds or changes *columns*, so the result will always include all observations / rows. To filter the observations, use the `filter` function from `dplyr` like this: (after you habe created the `n_days` column with `mutate`)

`Stock_Data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(n_days > 10000)`

Comment: Hi @AEF, thanks for your answer. Note on 2, I'm not extracting, I want the same length for the new column, therefore for those rows where the outcome is NA,  list will contain NA. Your answer at 1 is great and is what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, then approach 1) will probably sufficient :)